# Xerces Library and Qt

Tags: qt, cygwin, mingw, xerces

I'm trying to setup xerces so that I can use it in Qt Creator for Windows.

Does Qt support windows/linux binaries or do I have to compile it using mingw as a target? How one goes about compiling those libraries in Windows?

Answer (score 4):

No, you can't use libraries compiled for Linux under Windows. You'll have to either build it yourself or use existing Windows binary distribution. How that works in detail depends on the third-party library you want to use. The basic options are, in case you have to build it yourself: build it with MSVC under Windows, with mingw under Windows, or cross-compile it with mingw from e.g. Linux. MSVC tends to be less hassle under Windows, but mingw might just work as well.

*Important*: mingw and MSVC are ABI-incompatible when it comes to C++ libraries. You can't use e.g. a MSVC-built xerces in your mingw-Qt project, or a mingw-Xerces in an MSVC project. That only affects C++ libraries, not pure C ones.

Comment: Hi frank. Didn't follow you completely. You said I either build it with MSVC or mingw, but after in your second paragraph you say mingw and msvc are incompatible. Does that mean I can't use the MSVC built xerces in Qt (witch uses mingw to compile the code)?

Comment: Yes, if you're using Qt with mingw. You can also use Qt with MSVC though, see here: http://qt.nokia.com/downloads/windows-cpp-vs2008

Comment: ok, that one I didn't saw earlier. Will look into. Could you give some pointers on how to compile a library like xerces so that I can use in Qt/mingw? Do I need to user cygwin and compile it using configure from that? Thanks for your help, frank.

Comment: You don't want to use cygwin for that, because then the build will detect the cygwin environment and build against that instead of "native Windows". Just install mingw, the one shipped with the Qt SDK will do. How exactly xerces would be compiled depends on its buildsystem, so I don't know the details there.